# Windows store certificate Import certificate authority (ca.crt) + Host private key (host.key) + Host public key (host.der)

Tags: windows, certificate, store

I have a folder that contains : certificate authority (ca.crt) + Host private key (host.key) + Host public key (host.der) => My application reads directly from this folder (local path)

I want to store it (certificate + keys) in Windows store certificate => My application should read from Windows store certificate

I can import just certificate (ca.crt) in windows store certificate what about the 2 keys (host.key)+(host.der)

Any suggestion ??

Regards,

Comment: Make a PKCS#12 container from host.key and host.der. Then import pkcs#12 to windows store. You can use openssl to do that with command `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey host.key -in host.der -out host.p12 -name "host"`.

Comment: Thanks @pepo
Here I have certificate (ca.crt) and 2 keys (private host.key + public host.der) => 3 inputs 
cmd : openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey host.key -in ca.crt -out host.p12 -name "host" --> What about the public key (host.der) ?

[link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25996/how-to-import-a-private-key-in-windows)

Comment: Like the [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25996/how-to-import-a-private-key-in-windows) suggested you need to run command `openssl pkcs12 -export -out host.pfx -inkey host.key -in host.der -certfile ca.crt` It will add all 3 inputs to PKCS#12 container.